# Android Studio suddenly shows wrong encoding error on some files

Tags: android

I am working on a Project and everything went well until I have updated Android Studio to version 3.2.1.
Now the IDE shows me wrong encoding errors on some files. When I replace these files with my backup files the error is gone. But after some time it shows again these encoding errors.
I have searched for this problem but no one seems to have this problem.
I can build my project so that is not the problem but it is really annoying to always replace these files.
I also want to mention that I am working for over a year now on this project and till yesterday everything was good.
I have not imported files from another source like other people with similar errors.
It would be nice if someone could tell me what is wrong now.
The encoding in the Settings is set to UTF-8 
but the corrupted files shows me error File was loaded in the wrong encoding: UTF-8 
I am using Windows 10.
I am also unable to open any of my drawable pngs in the IDE, it only shows me a message that I should open the file externally and fix format problems. 
Is my Android Studio completely broken?
Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! All I needed to do was delete the iml files of my project and invalidate cache and everything was good.